# the images not displaying on Heroku

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

im trying to upload images on my app that's been served on heroku and it's says

ENOENT: no such file or directory

this is my code

```
router.post('/' ,multer({
  storage : multer.diskStorage({
    destination : (req , file , callback) => {
      callback (null,'img')
    } ,
    filename : (req , file  , callback) => {
      callback(null , Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname)
    }
  })
})
```

and the architecture of my files

- controllers
- img  **this is the folder i want to upload to**
- public
- routes
- views
- app.js

anyone can help >>>>?

Answer (score 0):

https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted

> Why are my file uploads missing/deleted?

> The Heroku filesystem is [ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) - that means that any changes to the filesystem whilst the dyno is running only last until that dyno is shut down or restarted. Each dyno boots with a clean copy of the filesystem from the most recent deploy. This is similar to how many container based systems, such as Docker, operate.

As a  solution to this, I'd recommend you use an image serving service like imgur.com or cloudinary.com.